# Кодировка в Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, кодировка, visual-studio-code

При запуске кода C++ с расшерения `Code Runner` в терминале показывает `╨Т╨▓╨╡╨┤╤Ц╤В╤М ╨┤╨╛╨▓╨╢╨╕╨╜╤Г ╨`. Но когда я ввожу в терминал `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")` оно работает нормально,как мне эту настройку сохранить чтобы каждый раз не вводить.

Comment: 1) SetConsoleCP(866); SetConsoleOutputCP(866); 2) setlocale(LC_ALL, ".866"); 3) system("chcp 866 > nul"); Попробуйте эти варианты в первых строчках main(). Консоль всегда в 866 кодировке выводит.
Я в VS Code не работаю, но думаю там есть настройка кодировки для редактора и если вы пишите консольки, то можно сразу там поменять кодировку как 866 и ничего писать потом не нужно =) Но если писать под Windows то менять на 1251.